# XSLT: using if in for-each with exceptions

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Hi I just started working with XSLT 3 Days ago and im stuck at a problem I cant find an answer to.
my xml looks something like this:

```
<process>
    <documents>
        <document>
            <titel>Doc1</titel>
        </document>
        <document>
            <titel>Doc2</titel>
        </document>
    </documents>
</process>
```

What im trying to do is creating an xml with a list of every document except the document with the titel "Doc1". I dont now how many documents will be in that file though.

So I thought starting with a for-each loop:

```
<documente>
    <xsl:for-each select="/process/documents[1]/document[1]/">
        <document filename="{titel}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</documente>
```

which gives me the titel of every document no matter how many there are (as an attribute to the element "document"). And now im kinda stuck.
I tried an if within for-each without success like this:

```
<documents>
    <xsl:for-each select="/process/documents[1]/document[1]/">
        <xsl:if test="/process/documents[1]/document[1]/element[@name='titel']/value[1]!='Doc1'">
            <document>
                <xsl:attribute name="filename">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/process/documents[1]/document[1]/element[@name='titel']/value[1]"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</documents>
```

And now Im grateful for every hint you might have.

Comment: The "/" at the end of a path expression (e.g. your `xsl:for-each/@select`) is a syntax error, and you shouldn't get any output except an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression

```
/process/documents[1]/document[1]/
```

is wrong because of the final "/": it should give you a syntax error.

If you change it to

```
/process/documents[1]/document[1]
```

then you are selecting the first `document` child of the first `documents` child of the `process` element. You aren't selecting "every document no matter how many there are" as you suggest in your question.

If you change it to

```
/process/documents[1]/document
```

then this is now selecting all the `document` elements.

If you want to put an xsl:if inside the xsl:for-each then you can. But remember that the context item inside xsl:for-each is the node selected by the xsl:for-each. So writing

```
<xsl:for-each select="/process/documents[1]/document">
    <xsl:if test="/process/documents[1]/document/titel = 'xyz'">
```

isn't going to be useful, because the `xsl:if` is starting from the root of the XML document, not from the currently-selected `document` element. Instead you want a relative path here:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/process/documents[1]/document">
    <xsl:if test="titel = 'xyz'">
```

But if the entire body of an `xsl:for-each` is an `xsl:if` instruction, then it's better practice to add a predicate to the `xsl:for-each/@select`, like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/process/documents[1]/document[titel = 'xyz']">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a plain XPath predicate you need on `document`, e.g. `document[titel != 'Doc1']`. No need for any XSLT instructions.

Comment: THANK YOU for your help!